# Ubuntu или Debian как Linux сервер

Tags: ubuntu, debian

Здравствуйте!

Я собираюсь запустить свой сайт. У хостера есть на выбор несколько Linux пресетов. Существенного опыта самостоятельного администрирования Linux сервера у меня нет. Но есть значительный опыт работы пользователем на Ubuntu и незначительный - на Debian.

Вопрос что выбрать: Debian или Ubuntu?

Comment: Я бы рекомендовал для сервера FreeBSD или CentOS. Была еще одна сборка для серверов, но я к сожалению забыл имя. Т.к. вопрос был в выборе из этих двух пишу в комментариях.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu и Debian - родственные дистрибутивы (точнее Ubuntu - произодный от Debian дистрибутив). Для серверной сборки некоторая разница будет в версиях пакетов, включаемых по умолчанию, и версиях пакетов, доступных из репозиториев. Кроме того, циклы выпуска обновлений/релизов отличаются.

Если Вы имеете опыт работы с десктопной версией Ubuntu, стоит ее и выбрать как серверный вариант, потому что Вам будет привычнее работать.

Answer (score 9):

Я бы лучше поставил Debian, благо он стабильнее чем Ubuntu. Да и сам довольно давно пользуюсь дебьяном.

Answer (score 3):

Выбрать тот дистрибутив, который лучше знаете вы или ваши админы.

Answer (score 1):

Для сервера - Debian

Answer (score 0):

Лучше Debian, обновление пакетов там производится после тщательного тестирования. Пакеты в Ubuntu чаще всего попадают из пакетов Debian, которые находятся на стадии тестирования.

Comment: Они не только более стабильные, но и более старые. Иногда это критично и стоит учитывать.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы тоже выбрал debian: он изначально позиционировался как серверная ОС, а Ubuntu - больше для конечного пользователя, хотя выбор между ними не критичен.

Answer (score 0):

Лучше берите Debian lenny, по нему можно найти больше хороших руководств, что важно для начинающего в области администрирования и он действительно стабильнее постоянно обновляющейся Ubuntu. Пусть он и не самый новый, зато на нем проще всего для начинающего.